# compute the floor of an integer division efficiently

Tags: go, integer-division

How can I efficiently compute the quotient of two integers, rounded down (not towards zero) in Go?  The following code seems to give the correct result, but looks awkward and inefficient:

```
func floorDiv(a, b int) int {
    if b < 0 {
        a, b = -a, -b
    }
    r := a % b
    if r < 0 {
        r += b
    }
    return (a - r) / b
}
```

(also on the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mWYwjqogE-4)).  Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you use [`math.Floor`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Floor)?

Comment: do you mean that (7/4) should return 2 instead of 1?  because in your code sample it will give 1, noting that 7/4 = 1.75

Comment: @MustafaSalman I want the result rounded down, so floor(7/4)=floor(1.75)=1 is what I want.  Also floor(-7/4)=floor(-1.75)=-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit twiddling is your friend here — I'll put this up against converting two integers to doubles and using `math.Floor()`.

```
func IntFloorDiv(x int, y int) int {
  q := x / y
  r := x % y
  
  if r != 0 && x&math.MinInt != y&math.MinInt {
    q -= 1
  }
  
  return q
}
```

Bit-twiddling allows us to easily identify the sign of a two's-complement integer:

- The smallest [negative] value that a two's-complement integer may contain has the sign bit set and the remaining bits all clear (`0x80000000`).
- A bitwise AND of an integer value against that smallest value gives us either 0 or the smallest value that that integer type may contain:

  - `5 & math.MinInt` yields 0
  - `0 & math.MinInt` yields 0
  - `-5 & Math.MinInt` yields `math.MinInt`

That lets us do this:

1. Compute the quotient and remainder for `x / y`.
2. If the remainder is zero, the quotient is ⌊ x / y ⌋.
3. Otherwise (the remainder is non-zero),

   1. If the sign bits differ, the quotient is negative and
      we must subtract 1 from the quotient to yield ⌊ x / y ⌋.
   2. if the sign bits are identical, the quotient is positive and
      the quotient is ⌊ x / y ⌋.

[Click here for the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/GXZ9e8PQkcw)

Results for `x` such that -10 ≤ `x` ≤ +10, and `y` = 3:

| X | Y | ⌊X÷Y⌋ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -10 | 3 | -4 |
| -9 | 3 | -3 |
| -8 | 3 | -3 |
| -7 | 3 | -3 |
| -6 | 3 | -2 |
| -5 | 3 | -2 |
| -4 | 3 | -2 |
| -3 | 3 | -1 |
| -2 | 3 | -1 |
| -1 | 3 | -1 |
| 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 | 3 |

## Benchmarks

Benchmark timings across 5 different runs show that converting to float and using `math.Floor()` to be nearly 21x slower than integer division and bit twiddling.

[Whether or not that actually matters is entirely dependent on the use case.]

The benchmark code calls the function being benchmarked 21x per loop iteration (for -10 to +10 inclusive) so the cost of the loop code doesn't mask the function being benchmarked.

```sh
❯ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: foobar.com/floordiv
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Benchmark_floorDiv_Int-8        1000000000               0.2730 ns/op
Benchmark_floorDiv_Math-8       189576496                5.969 ns/op
PASS
ok      foobar.com/floordiv     2.266s

❯ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: foobar.com/floordiv
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Benchmark_floorDiv_Int-8        1000000000               0.2718 ns/op
Benchmark_floorDiv_Math-8       196402200                5.954 ns/op
PASS
ok      foobar.com/floordiv     2.243s

❯ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: foobar.com/floordiv
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Benchmark_floorDiv_Int-8        1000000000               0.2756 ns/op
Benchmark_floorDiv_Math-8       200432154                5.976 ns/op
PASS
ok      foobar.com/floordiv     2.271s

❯ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: foobar.com/floordiv
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Benchmark_floorDiv_Int-8        1000000000               0.2814 ns/op
Benchmark_floorDiv_Math-8       195009298                6.083 ns/op
PASS
ok      foobar.com/floordiv     2.314s

❯ go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: foobar.com/floordiv
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Benchmark_floorDiv_Int-8        1000000000               0.2751 ns/op
Benchmark_floorDiv_Math-8       201196482                6.033 ns/op
PASS
ok      foobar.com/floordiv     2.290s
```

running this benchmark:

```
package main

import (
  "math"
  "testing"
)

func floorDiv_Int(x int, y int) int {
  q := x / y
  r := x % y
  
  if r != 0 && x&math.MinInt != y&math.MinInt {
    q -= 1
    }
  
  return q
}

func floorDiv_Math(x int, y int) int {
  return int(math.Floor(
    float64(x) / float64(y),
  ))
}

func Benchmark_floorDiv_Int(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    floorDiv_Int(-10, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-9, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-8, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-7, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-6, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-5, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-4, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-3, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-2, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(-1, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(0, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(1, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(2, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(3, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(4, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(5, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(6, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(7, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(8, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(9, 3)
    floorDiv_Int(10, 3)
  }
}

func Benchmark_floorDiv_Math(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    floorDiv_Math(-10, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-9, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-8, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-7, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-6, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-5, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-4, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-3, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-2, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(-1, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(0, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(1, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(2, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(3, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(4, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(5, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(6, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(7, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(8, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(9, 3)
    floorDiv_Math(10, 3)
  }
}
```

Comment: That "bit kungfu" plays no performance role here. To test if a number is negative, you can simply write `x < 0`. If you write it like `if r != 0 && ((x < 0) != (y < 0)) {}`, you get the same performance.

Comment: @icza why do I get a faster bench with `if  a%b != 0 && a*b < 0 {}` is comparing slower than multiplication

Comment: @MustafaSalman Likely some low level optimization. `a` and `b` are already loaded in CPU registers, while comparing with a value needs additional instructions. You have to look at the generated assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the integers to float64, divide, and use [`math.Floor`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#Floor).

```
func floorDiv(a, b int) int {
  return int(math.Floor(float64(a)/float64(b)))
}
```

Benchmarking shows they run in about the same time, and the same as a simple add function.

```
func BenchmarkFloorDiv(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    _ = floorDiv(i, 3)
  }
}

func BenchmarkFloorDivGo(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    _ = floorDivGo(i, 3)
  }
}

func BenchmarkFloorAdd(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    _ = add(i, 3)
  }
}

goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/my/repo/test_go
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8559U CPU @ 2.70GHz
BenchmarkFloorDiv-8         1000000000           0.2612 ns/op
BenchmarkFloorDivGo-8       1000000000           0.2610 ns/op
BenchmarkFloorAdd-8         1000000000           0.2565 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/my/repo/test_go  1.000s
```

This suggests it's so fast we're just benchmarking the loop. It is unlikely to be a bottleneck, I would suggest the simplest option.

Comment: It's funny how closely the speeds match.  Coincidence?

Comment: @jochen I also benchmarked a simple `a + b` function and got the same result. Might be too fast to benchmark this way and it's just measuring the loop. It suggests this will not be a performance bottleneck and you should go with the simplest.

Comment: Measure a million execution instead of just one, to amortize the benchmarking loop's overhead: `for j := 0; j < 1_000_000; j++ { floorDiv(i, 3) }`. This will show the `math.Floor()` solution is roughly twice as fast.

Comment: @icza The benchmark loop is just a for loop; you've put a for loop in a for loop. It shouldn't have any effect, but it does. Weird.

Comment: under the hood `math.Floor` might use spcecific calls if the architecture allows it. https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.8:src/math/floor.go;l=14

Answer (score 2):

The benchmark in case multiply numbers (a*b) will be faster:-

```golang
func floorDivMustafa2(a, b int) int {

    if a%b != 0 && a*b < 0 {
        return a/b - 1
    }
    return a / b
}
```

I tried the Xor method but it is slower:

```golang
//xor method
func floorDivMustafa(a, b int) int {

    if a%b != 0 && (a < 0 || b < 0) && !(a < 0 && b < 0) {
        return a/b - 1
    }
    return a / b
}
```

this is my unit test method

```golang
func Test_floorDivSchwern(t *testing.T) {

    var (
        got, want int
    )

    for a := -10; a < 10; a++ {
        for b := -10; b < 10; b++ {
            if b == 0 {
                continue
            }
            got = floorDivMustafa(a, b)
            want = floorDivSchwern(a, b)
            if got != want {
                t.Errorf("divRound(%v/%v) = %v, want %v", a, b, got, want)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the bench-mark method:

```golang
func BenchmarkFloorDivMustafa2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for a := -100; a < 100; a++ {
            for b := -100; b < 100; b++ {
                if b == 0 {
                    continue
                }
                _ = floorDivMustafa2(a, b)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output for all:

```
>>>go test -bench=^Benchmark  -benchtime=1000x

BenchmarkSchwern-4                  1000            182345 ns/op
BenchmarkFloorDivMustafa-4          1000            441682 ns/op
BenchmarkFloorDivMustafa2-4         1000             31234 ns/op
BenchmarkJochen-4                   1000             60315 ns/op
BenchmarkIntfolurdiv-4              1000          26437611 ns/op
BenchmarkFloorDivICza-4             1000          26406776 ns/op
```

**Edit** after I saw the result of Bit twiddling slower in my benchmark I try the bench method of the op and this is my result:

```
BenchmarkTwentyNumberBitwise-4                    328639            113790 ns/op
BenchmarkTwentyNumberMultiplication-4             295512            101345 ns/op
```

Comment: WARNING: don't use this version if your numbers are sufficiently large - for reference, I was calculating (1782432000 + 8520336000) // (879995520 + 4177926720) and floorDivMustafa2 gives an (erroneous) answer of 1. The other two algorithms do give the correct answer.

 (see https://play.golang.com/p/76aQT1xgPQw).